# How to get current URL from Chrome from a Node JS app

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want my Node js app to be able to get the URL of the active tab in the active Chrome window. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Right now, I have the Node app simulate typing a key combo using kbm-robot that is watched for in the browser via an extension that relays the URL by means of an http request back to the Node app. This works on one machine, but I am difficulty making work on another machine. And of course this solution is a kludge, so I am looking for a better approach.

Can WebRTC possibly apply here?

I would prefer a cross platform solution, but it really only needs to work on Windows right now.

Comment: can you provide some code for us to look at?

Comment: I am afraid, I don't see the point. The approach I am using is a hack. I am looking for a better approach in general.

Comment: Anything you use to access the Chrome process from a Node process is going to be a hack.